# How to change date format (MM/DD/YY) to (YYYY-MM-DD) in date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, calendar

I have following datepicker script:

```
<script>
 $(function(){
        $("#to").datepicker();
        $("#from").datepicker().bind("change",function(){
            var minValue = $(this).val();
            minValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", minValue);
            minValue.setDate(minValue.getDate()+1);
            $("#to").datepicker( "option", "minDate", minValue );
        })
    });
</script>
```

Now dateformat is MM/DD/YY .how to change the date format to YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: Do you want to change the parseDate format or the actual displayed dateformat?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use the [`dateFormat`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#options) option

```
 $(function(){
        $("#to").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
        $("#from").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).bind("change",function(){
            var minValue = $(this).val();
            minValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", minValue);
            minValue.setDate(minValue.getDate()+1);
            $("#to").datepicker( "option", "minDate", minValue );
        })
    });
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/WArtA/

Comment: Here is my problem: I want the date displayed on screen to be "mm/dd/yy" but I want the DOM to store "yy-mm-dd" since it will be sent to mySQL upon submit. Is this possible?

Comment: @circle1 see the [`altFormat`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altFormat) and [`altField`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField) options.

Comment: I found those later yesterday and you're right, it is designed to do exactly what I need.

Answer (score 39):

Try the following:

```
$('#to').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

You'd think it would be yyyy-mm-dd but oh well :P

Comment: Also folks, be careful to write `mm` in small caps, since `MM` will display the month in letters.

Comment: this works for me, and be careful its dateFormat dont mistype to dateformat

Answer (score 25):

I had the same issue and I have tried many answers but nothing worked.

I tried the following and it worked successfully :

```
<input type=text  data-date-format='yy-mm-dd'  >
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'yy-mm-dd' );
```

See:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/
and
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate#utility-formatDate

Answer (score 4):

If in jquery the dateformat option is not working then we can handle this situation in html page in input field of your date:

```html
<input type="text" data-date-format='yyyy-mm-dd'  id="selectdateadmin" class="form-control" required>
```

And in javascript below this page add your date picker code:

```js
 $('#selectdateadmin').focusin( function()
     {
       $("#selectdateadmin").datepicker();
       
     });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this during the initialization of your datepicker:

```
$("#your_elements_id").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd' });
```

Answer (score 2):

this also worked for me. Go to the **bootstrap-datepicker.js**.

replace this code :

```js
var defaults = $.fn.datepicker.defaults = {
  autoclose: false,
  beforeShowDay: $.noop,
  calendarWeeks: false,
  clearBtn: false,
  daysOfWeekDisabled: [],
  endDate: Infinity,
  forceParse: true,
  format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
  keyboardNavigation: true,
  language: 'en',
  minViewMode: 0,
  multidate: false,
  multidateSeparator: ',',
  orientation: "auto",
  rtl: false,
  startDate: -Infinity,
  startView: 0,
  todayBtn: false,
  todayHighlight: false,
  weekStart: 0
 };
```

with :

```js
var defaults = $.fn.datepicker.defaults = {
  autoclose: false,
  beforeShowDay: $.noop,
  calendarWeeks: false,
  clearBtn: false,
  daysOfWeekDisabled: [],
  endDate: Infinity,
  forceParse: true,
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  keyboardNavigation: true,
  language: 'en',
  minViewMode: 0,
  multidate: false,
  multidateSeparator: ',',
  orientation: "auto",
  rtl: false,
  startDate: -Infinity,
  startView: 0,
  todayBtn: false,
  todayHighlight: false,
  weekStart: 0
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

I used this approach to perform the same operation in my app.

```
var varDate = $("#dateStart").val(); 

var DateinISO = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', varDate); 

var DateNewFormat = $.datepicker.formatDate( "yy-mm-dd", new Date( DateinISO ) );

$("#dateStartNewFormat").val(DateNewFormat);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", minValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.formatDate( format, date, settings )`

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate

Answer (score 1):

just add `dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'` to your `.datepicker({})` settings, your `.datepicker({})` can look something like this

```
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                showButtonPanel: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
            });
          });

    </script>
```

Comment: This was already in the accepted answer, What does your answer add beyond that?

Answer (score 1):

Just need to define **yy-mm-dd** here. **dateFormat**

Default is **mm-dd-yy**

Change mm-dd-yy to yy-mm-dd. Look example below

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
    });
  } );

Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all. I got my expected output

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
        $("#to").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
        $("#from").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).bind("change",function(){
            var minValue = $(this).val();
            minValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", minValue);
            minValue.setDate(minValue.getDate()+1);
            $("#to").datepicker( "option", "minDate", minValue );
        })
    });

</script> 

<div class="">
    <p>From Date: <input type="text" id="from"></p>

    <p>To Date: <input type="text" id="to"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/8w8v9/) worked for me.

```
    $('#thedate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    altField: '#thealtdate',
    altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
 $('#data_compra').daterangepicker({
          singleDatePicker: true,
          locale: {
           format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
          },
         calender_style: "picker_4", }, 
function(start, end, label) {
          console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in every datePicker version, firstly converting date into internal datePicker date format, and then converting it back to desired one

```
var date = "2017-11-07";   
date = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd.mm.yy", $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', date));
// 07.11.2017
```

Answer (score 0):

For me in datetimepicker jquery plugin format:'d/m/Y' option is worked

```
$("#dobDate").datetimepicker({
lang:'en',
timepicker:false,
autoclose: true,
format:'d/m/Y',
onChangeDateTime:function( ct ){
   $(".xdsoft_datetimepicker").hide();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $('#selectdateadmin').focusin( function()
     {
       $("#selectdateadmin").datepicker();
       
     });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.