# How to Change JS DatePicker Format to MM-DD-YY?

Tags: javascript

How would you change the date result format to be MM-DD-YY rather than MM/DD/YY in my code below?

```
 <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#input5" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
```

I found this but I am not able to make it work with my code although I assume I am just doing something wrong :(
 [How to change date format (MM/DD/YY) to (YYYY-MM-DD) in date picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500058/how-to-change-date-format-mm-dd-yy-to-yyyy-mm-dd-in-date-picker)

Comment: There are numerous different datepicker plugins. How you do it depends on the documentation for the one you are using. So which one is it?

Comment: This is the full scripts I am using <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#input5" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>

Comment: @Thomas Try my answer and if it doesn't work out let me know.

Comment: could you show all the error messages?

Comment: WHat is shown in linked answers is correct so provide a [mcve] where it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats), you should use this way:

```
$( function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "mm-dd-yy" );
} );
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. THANK YOU!!

Comment: Most would pass option object to first call

Comment: @charlietfl Not sure, for some reason that's not working bro. What to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Bootstrap Datepicker library  and set the format to `'mm-dd-yy'` like this `format: 'mm-dd-yy'`.

```html
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"   integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#from-datepicker").datepicker({ 
        format: 'mm-dd-yy'
    });
    $("#from-datepicker").on("change", function () {
        var fromdate = $(this).val();
        alert(fromdate);
    });
}); 
</script>
<input type="text" id="from-datepicker"/>
```