# TextBox date control - date format customization asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am using a TextBox control for calendar where user can select date from calendar,.aspx code is as below

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPaymentDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            $("#<%=txtPaymentDate.ClientID%>").datepicker({
            autoclose: true
        });              
    }
    </script>
```

This gives me date in `MM/DD/YYYY` fromat, example: `09/20/2017`

I want the date in `DD/MM/YYYY` format, trying to get the same but failed.Pl provide me the syntax to get the `DD/MM/YYYY` date format

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7500058/284240

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328025/jquery-ui-datepicker-change-date-format

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yogesh078/6wyp1udx/24/

Answer (score 2):

You can add dateFormat option:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPaymentDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        $("#<%=txtPaymentDate.ClientID%>").datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
    });              
}
</script>
```

Reference: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat