# .Net Core 2.0 Setting Culture Info to en-GB for Date Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to set my WEB API Application to accept post requests that include a DateTime property which is passed through in dd/MM/yyyy format.

In my Startup class, i have configured the request localization as follows :-

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            //app.UseAuthentication();
            var supportedCultures = new[]
            {

                new CultureInfo("en-AU"),
                new CultureInfo("en-GB"),
                new CultureInfo("en"),
                new CultureInfo("es-ES"),
                new CultureInfo("es-MX"),
                new CultureInfo("es"),
                new CultureInfo("fr-FR"),
                new CultureInfo("fr"),
            };

            app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-GB"),
                // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
                SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
                // UI strings that we have localized.
                SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
            });

            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

However, Model binding fails on a test date such as 22/12/1977. For me the middleware is being ignored.

Comment: Web API uses JSON. While there's no standard date format, everyone uses the ISO 8601 format. Why are you trying to change to something guaranteed to confuse every client of the API? It's the *client's* job to send correctly formatted data.

Comment: If you need a conversion based on a specific culture, why not accept a string and convert manually?

Comment: Thats a good point @Sefe

Comment: BTW if the client is a web page, all that's needed to send the correct format is to call `.toISOString()` on a Date object instead of `toString()` or accepting raw user input

Comment: @Derek not really - the *clients* won't know that you are breaking the convention. If you use MVC in the same project it's trivial to send the correct dates back to the API controllers

Comment: @Derek if you are using eg jQuery DatePicker [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500058/how-to-change-date-format-mm-dd-yy-to-yyyy-mm-dd-in-date-picker/37473649) shows how to use the `dateformat` parameter or the `data-date-format` data binding attribute