# How to change date format (MM/DD/YY) to (DD/MM/YYYY) in date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
this.locale = {
        direction: 'ltr',
        format: moment.localeData().longDateFormat('L'),
        separator: ' - ',
        applyLabel: 'Apply',
        cancelLabel: 'Cancel',
        weekLabel: 'W',
        customRangeLabel: 'Custom Range',
        daysOfWeek: moment.weekdaysMin(),
        monthNames: moment.monthsShort(),
        firstDay: moment.localeData().firstDayOfWeek()
    };
```

Now date format is MM/DD/YYYY .how to change the date format to DD-MM-YYYY

Comment: Posible duplate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/7500139/6727154

Comment: this solution is for mm-dd-yyyy format but i need dd-mm-yyyy format

Comment: Have you ever tried to change the date format in the answer that i shared?

Comment: I already tried it but did not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change date format (MM/DD/YY) to (YYYY-MM-DD) in date picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500058/how-to-change-date-format-mm-dd-yy-to-yyyy-mm-dd-in-date-picker)

Comment: You should start with the API documentation or a google search before you ask a question that has been answered several times.

Answer (score 0):

Use Datepicker's **dateFormat** option:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
});
```

More usage instructions and a link to all different formatting options can be found here: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat